# Missions failed before launch

Tags: launch, failure, statistics

The [Falcon 9 - Amos-6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amos-6) - mission in 3 September 2016 failed before launch - the rocket exploded during the static fire test.

Some lists contain such missions but others don't - like for example [Jonathan C. McDowell's JSR launch database](https://planet4589.org/space/gcat/data/derived/currentcat.html).

What other such missions failed before launch? I mean catastrophic failures that end in the loss of the rocket

The list include:

- after ignition but before release of clamps
- test ignition a day or two or more before launch
- during count-down count

Comment: Does this include catastrophic failures caused by a rocket mishap only?

Comment: You can probably begin by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_the_Moon and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missions_to_Mars which include quite a lot of failures. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_space_missions.

Comment: Failures during countdown and test ignition failures do not really need to mean final mission failures - the mission might have later started without problems.

Comment: It seems strange to equate failure of the mission and loss of the rocket. SpaceX offered the choice to install the payload either before or after the static fire. Spacecom *chose* to have Amos-6 put on the rocket before the static fire. They could have made a different choice, which would have meant a catastrophic failure that ends in the loss of the rocket, but not a failure of the mission.

Comment: If the mission fails before launch that means the rocket is lost. If the rocket is not lost then it can launch. If there is a launch then there is no failure before launch.

Answer (score 4):

The [Soyuz_7K-OK_No.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_7K-OK_No.1) comes to mind. After an aborted launch, the launch escape system was triggered by the rotation of the earth. It fire approx. 27 minutes after the scrapped launch.

[Here's Scott Manley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9u0ymYbyAtA) telling the story of this particular accident.